# How To Send Notifications To A Specific User Group / Role Only using Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, socket.io-1.0

I am working on a project which I want to implement a feature where after an action happens, I want to notify all online administrators on the web app and show them a message that an action happened.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I identify which user is online and has an admin role? I am looking for some ideas around "show all online users" list
2. Should I put these admins into a room where I can broadcast the notification  only to that room?
3. How can I get all users who are online and associate their socket ID with the ID / Username in the database?

I will also need the online status to be shown in a table so I can know if UserOne and John are online at the moment.

4. How can I keep the online / offline status? Do I have to keep the status somewhere outside of the database?

I am using Laravel v5.1, NodeJS v5.0, Socket.io v1.3 and Redis to play around with the notifications.

Does anyone have any idea how can I deal with this problem? I am not really looking for any code specific stuff, I am just curious about the theory behind the idea and how it will work.

Thanks!